# Open File dialogs mouse navigation (5 buttons) back and forward wanted

Tags: mouse, navigation

I use a [5 button mouse](https://www.amazon.de/Rapoo-N3600-Optical-konfigurierbare-Tasten/dp/B00SLGQX1A/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1492958581&sr=8-1&keywords=rapoo%20n3600) to navigate in Ubuntu. For navigating back and forward in the web i use the 2 buttons on the left side of the mouse. They also work inside Gnome but not in the Open File dialogs.

Is there a way to make them work in the Open File dialogs?